# Does $\|x\|_{\ell^\infty }\leq C\|x\|_{\ell^2}$ for a constant $C$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $$\ell^2=\left\{x\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\mid \|x\|_2:=\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^\infty |x_i|^2}<\infty \right\}$$

and 
$$\ell^\infty =\left\{x\in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}\mid \|x\|_\infty :=\sup_{i\in\mathbb N}|x_i|<\infty \right\}.$$

I think that $\Phi:\ell^2\to \ell^\infty $ defined by $\Phi(x)=x$ is not continuous, but I can't find a sequence $x^n=(x_i^n)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ of $\ell^2$ s.t. $$\frac{\|x^n\|_\infty }{\|x^n\|_2 }\to \infty\quad \text{when}\  n\to \infty .$$
Any idea ?

Comment: The inequality holds with $C = 1$.  The reverse inequality, however, does not hold.  So $\Phi$ is continuous, but $\Phi^{-1}$ is not.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Well, acctually $\Phi^{-1}$ is a priori not well defined, no ? (since for example $(1)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is in $\ell^\infty $ but not in $\ell^2$). Thank you

Comment: The inverse of $\Phi$, as a function, is well-defined, because it's injective. $1$ is not in the range of $\Phi$, so you can't "put it into" the inverse of $\Phi$.

Comment: @Walace I suppose I meant for $\Phi^{-1}$ to be a map on the image of $\Phi$, i.e. $\ell^2 \subset \ell^\infty$.